# Relative path to static files in Express Mustache template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache

I am facing an issue with relative urls when the page is rendered using Mustache template engine in Express.js.

I have defined a route like `app.get('/procedure/:procedure', templateEngine.getProcedureDescription);` to get the html page to be rendered on click of a link `<a href="procedure/IVF">Read More</a>`

url gets redirected to `http://localhost:1557/procedure/IVF` on click of the above link.

All my CSS and JS files are placed in assets folder in root directory and it's loaded using a relative url `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/plugins.min.css">`.

In my case when the page gets rendered, the browser is deriving the url as 
 `http://localhost:1337/procedure/asset/css/plugins.min.css` whereas the actual path of the file is `http://localhost:1337/asset/css/plugins.min.css`.

What is the change I need to make in href, route or relative path a get all the css files loaded?

Comment: Ensure you have created a directory for all static files and then tell express to use that directory `app.use(express.static('public'));`